# Golang SQL rows.Scan function for all fields of generic type

Tags: sql, go, generics, select

I want to use the `Scan()` function from the *sql* package for executing a select statement that might (or not) return multiple rows, and return these results in my function.

I´m new to Golang **generics**, and am confused about how to achieve this.
Usually, we would use the `Scan` function on a `*sql.Rows` and provide the references to all fields of our expected 'result type' we want to read the rows into, e.g.:

```
var alb Album
rows.Scan(&alb.ID, &alb.Title, &alb.Artist,
            &alb.Price, &alb.Quantity)
```

where Album is a struct type with those five fields shown.

Now, for the purpose of not writing a similar function N times for every SQL table I have, I want to use a **generic type *R*** instead. R is of generic interface type Result, and I will define this type as one of N different structs:

```
type Result interface {
    StructA | StructB | StructC
}

func ExecSelect[R Result](conn *sql.DB, cmd Command, template R) []R
```

How can I now write `rows.Scan(...)` to apply the Scan operation on all fields of my struct of R´s concrete type? e.g. I would want to have `rows.Scan(&res.Field1, &res.Field2, ...)` where res is of type R, and Scan should receive all fields of my current concrete type R. And do I actually need to provide a 'template' as argument of R´s concrete type, so that at runtime it becomes clear which struct is now relevant?

Please correct me on any mistake I´m making considering the generics.

Answer (score 2):

This is a poor use case for generics.

The arguments to the function [`sql.Rows.Scan`](https://pkg.go.dev/database/sql#Rows.Scan) are supposed to be the scan destinations, i.e. your struct fields, one for each column in the result set, and within the generic function body you [do not have access to the fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70358216/how-can-i-define-a-struct-field-in-my-interface-as-a-type-constraint-type-t-has/70361353#70361353) of `R` type parameter.

Even if you did, the structs in your `Result` constraint likely have different fields...? So how do you envision writing **generic** code that works with **different** fields?

You might accomplish what you want with a package that provides arbitrary struct scanning like `sqlx` with facilities like [`StructScan`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/jmoiron/sqlx#Rows.StructScan), but that uses reflection under the hood to map the struct fields into `sql.Rows.Scan` arguments, so you are not getting any benefit at all with generics.

If anything, you are making it worse, because now you have the additional performance overheads of using type parameters.

Answer (score 2):

Another answer shows how to create a map of [types](https://godoc.org/reflect#Type) as asked in the question.  You don't actually need a map of types.

For each type, you need a function to create a pointer to a new value and a function to deference the pointer.  Let's declare an interface for the required functionality:

```
type FieldTyper interface {
    // Return pointer to new value.
    New() (ptr any)
    // Dereference pointer.
    Deref(ptr any) (val any)
}
```

Create a generic implementation of that interface:

```
type FieldType[T any] struct{}

func (v FieldType[T]) New() any {
    return new(T)
}

func (v FieldType[T]) Deref(p any) any {
    return *p.(*T)
}
```

Create a map of column names to FieldTypers:

```
var fieldTypes = map[string]FieldTyper{
    "id":   FieldType[Type_int]{},
    "name": FieldType[Type_string]{},
}
```

Use the field typers to setup the scan args and deference those args and add to map.

```
func SetupScanArgs(columnNames []string, fieldTypes map[string]FieldTyper) []any {
    args := make([]any, len(columnNames))
    for i, n := range columnNames {
        args[i] = fieldTypes[n].New()
    }
    return args
}

func ArgsToValueMap(columnNames []string, fieldTypes map[string]FieldTyper, args []any) map[string]any {
    result := make(map[string]any)
    for i, n := range columnNames {
        result[n] = fieldTypes[n].Deref(args[i])
    }
    return result
}
```

Scan like this:

```
args := SetupScanArgs(columnNames, fieldTypes)
if err := rows.Scan(args...); err != nil {
    return err
}
m := ArgsToValueMap(columnNames, fieldTypes, args)
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the reflect package:

```
func scan(rows *sql.Rows, types map[string]reflect.Type) (map[string]any, error) {
    names, _ := rows.Columns()
    ptrs := make([]any, len(names))
    vals := make([]reflect.Value, len(names))
    for i, n := range names {
        vals[i] = reflect.New(types[n])
        ptrs[i] = vals[i].Interface()
    }
    if err := rows.Scan(ptrs...); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    result := make(map[string]any)
    for i, v := range vals {
        result[names[i]] = v.Elem().Interface()
    }
    return result, nil
}
```

where `types` is something like this:

```
types = map[string]reflect.Type{
   "id": reflect.TypeOf(Type_int(0)),
   "name": reflect.TypeOf(Type_string("")),
}
```