# In Go can I use generics to declare the same method to different structs?

Tags: go, generics

Is there a way to use golang 1.18 generics with struct methods? Ie something like this such that I have a common method `SayName` for both `Foo` and `Bar`:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Foo struct {
    Name     string
    Number   int
    FooID string
}

type Bar struct {
    Name     string
    Number   int
    BarID string
}

func  [T Foo|Bar](x *T) SayName() {
    fmt.Printf("%d \"%s\"", x.Number, x.Name)
}

func main() {
    foo := Foo{Name: "Name 1", Number: 1, FooID: "Foo123"}
    foo.SayName()

    bar := Bar{Name: "Name 2", Number: 2, BarID: "Bar456"}
    bar.SayName()
}
```

*I know this can be done in other ways using a base type and struct embedding or interfaces on each, but this is just a contrived example to keep things simple.*

UPDATE: To make this more clear, what if I have a slightly less contrived example like below. I know about struct embedding and using base interfaces. But in the case below if `SayName` was defined as `func (b *Base) SayName() {...` I would get a run time error because the `Base` type does not have the `GetID` interface (it would be `nil`). So I want to pass in a generic which will have this interface on the `Foo` and `Bar` instances. Am I missing something?

For instance this code below would all work if I duplicate the `SayName` function for each type (as seen in the commented out section)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Base struct {
    Name   string
    Number int
}

type GetIDIface interface {
    GetID() string
}

type Foo struct {
    Base
    GetIDIface
    FooID string
}

func (f *Foo) GetID() string {
    return f.FooID
}

type Bar struct {
    Base
    GetIDIface
    BarID string
}

func (b *Bar) GetID() string {
    return b.BarID
}

func  [T Foo|Bar](x *T) SayName() {
    fmt.Printf("Number %d \"%s\" with ID of %s", x.Number, x.Name, x.GetID())
}

/* THIS WORKS
func (x *Foo) SayName() {
    fmt.Printf("Number %d \"%s\" with ID of %s\n", x.Number, x.Name, x.GetID())
}

func (x *Bar) SayName() {
    fmt.Printf("Number %d \"%s\" with ID of %s\n", x.Number, x.Name, x.GetID())
}*/

func main() {
    foo := Foo{Base: Base{Name: "Name 1", Number: 1}, FooID: "Foo123"}
    foo.SayName()

    bar := Bar{Base: Base{Name: "Name 2", Number: 2}, BarID: "Bar456"}
    bar.SayName()
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean "a generic struct"? Neither of your struct types here are generic in the sense of 1.18 generics.

Comment: Embedding is probably more appropriate here. With contrived examples like this it is hard to make great recommendations.

Comment: @HymnsForDisco Does the second bit of code make the question more clear ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The boring and overall better solution is to declare those methods on each struct that needs them.** This also makes the structs implement a hypothetical interface with `SayName()` method, should you need it. Beyond that, there is no language construct to declare the same method on different receivers.

What you *could* (but not necessarily *should*) do, is using a generic struct with a type constraint that restricts to `Foo` and `Bar`, however [you can't access common fields of those structs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70358216/how-can-i-define-a-struct-field-in-my-interface-as-a-type-constraint-type-t-has). So the constraint couldn't even be `Foo | Bar` as we'd all like; instead you'd need methods to access those fields.

In your case you already have the `GetIDIface`, which `Foo` and `Bar` implement, so you can embed that:

```
type FooBar interface {
    Foo | Bar
    GetIDIface
}

type Base[T FooBar] struct {
    Item   T
    Name   string
    Number int
}

func (x *Base[T]) SayName() {
    fmt.Printf("Number %d \"%s\" with ID of %s\n", x.Number, x.Name, x.Item.GetID())
}
```

You can see the complete example in the [playground](https://go.dev/play/p/pZxYDhWsSth).

**However this reverses the relationship between `Base` and `Foo`/`Bar`**. I.e. `Base` is not really a "base" anymore; it's a wrapper. Make sure it fits the semantics of your application, if you want to go down this route.

---

An alternative is to use a top level function that takes an interface with the necessary functionality. This way generics aren't needed:

```
type Base struct {
    Name   string
    Number int
}

// Add getter on the base type itself
func (b Base) GetBase() Base {
    return b
}

type Foo struct {
    Base // embedding Base promotes GetBase() too
    FooID string
}
// other Foo methods

type Bar struct {
    Base // embedding Base promotes GetBase() too
    BarID string
}
// other Bar methods

// interface with required functionality
type Sayer interface {
    GetBase() Base
    GetIDIface
}

func SayName(x Sayer) {
    fmt.Printf("Number %d \"%s\" with ID of %s\n", x.GetBase().Number, x.GetBase().Name, x.GetID())
}
```

Playground: https://go.dev/play/p/4RBxW9D53Q8

Comment: Hey, thanks for the post ... I never thought about having a wrapper type around the lot ... I don't think it really works all that well for me though as its quite a pain to wrap all your variables up as a new type just to call a function ... If there is no better solution I will accept this as the answer, but it seems like a pretty painful limitation in go if the only way to do this is to repeat the function over and over on each type

Comment: @othane an alternative is to use a top level function that takes an interface with the methods you need, including `GetBase() Base` that returns the embedded field in each struct. `GetBase` can be declared on `Base` itself and promoted into each struct by embedding. https://go.dev/play/p/4RBxW9D53Q8